# angularjs post Radio Button group collection (Save every group checked choice in array Or Post choices to the server)

Tags: angularjs

" I'm new in angularjs "

**1- Scenario Description:**
    - We are Making Something like Survey ,
    - Many Questions , every Question contains many Answers ,
    - The Questions and it's answers rendered automatically from database using angularjs
    - When user finish the Survey just click Save to post selected choices to the server

**2- The problem** :
    - Using "angularjs" How can i Collect the user choices in array or post the selected choices to the server.

**Code** : https://jsfiddle.net/6kxx2vLu/

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rud3F.jpg)

===================== angularjs And HTML =====================

```
<div ng-app="massApp" ng-controller="massCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="question in Questions">
            <h1>{{question.questionAR}}</h1>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="answerChoice in question.answerChoices">
                    <div ng-if="answerChoice.answerChoiceTypeId == '1' ">
                        <label for="elmnt{{question.questionId}}">
                            {{answerChoice.answerChoiceAr}}
                        </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="elmnt{{question.questionId}}" value="{{answerChoice.answerChoiceId}}" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input ng-click="saveAnswers()" type="button" value="Save" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        //------
        var moCdataForTest = [{
            "questionId": 20,
            "questionAR": "How you Know Our Services?",
            "surveyId": 12,
            "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
            "answerChoices": [
             {
                 "answerChoiceId": 1,
                 "questionId": 20,
                 "answerChoiceAr": "From web or Google Serach",
                 "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
             },
             {
                 "answerChoiceId": 2,
                 "questionId": 20,
                 "answerChoiceAr": "From Frind",
                 "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
             },
             {
                 "answerChoiceId": 3,
                 "questionId": 20,
                 "answerChoiceAr": "Newspaper ads",
                 "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
             }
            ]
        },
       {
           "questionId": 21,
           "questionAR": "What is your satisfaction level?",
           "surveyId": 12,
           "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
           "answerChoices": [
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 4,
                "questionId": 21,
                "answerChoiceAr": "Good",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            },
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 5,
                "questionId": 21,
                "answerChoiceAr": "Very Good",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            },
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 6,
                "questionId": 21,
                "answerChoiceAr": "Excellent",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            }
           ]
       },
       {
           "questionId": 23,
           "questionAR": "What is Visit Rate?",
           "surveyId": 12,
           "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
           "answerChoices": [
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 4,
                "questionId": 23,
                "answerChoiceAr": "1Star",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            },
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 5,
                "questionId": 23,
                "answerChoiceAr": "2Star",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            },
            {
                "answerChoiceId": 6,
                "questionId": 23,
                "answerChoiceAr": "3Star",
                "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
            }
           ]
       }]
        //-------
        var massApp = angular.module("massApp", []);
        //-------
        massApp.controller("massCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.Questions = moCdataForTest;
            $scope.saveAnswers = function () {
                alert('Data Saved');
            }
        });
        //-------
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `ng-model`.

I see you are using Angular 1.2. In this version `ng-model` does not support getter/setter feature so it cannot add/remove from array.

So, you'll need to change `userAnswers` to be an object instead of an array.

```
$scope.userAnswers = {};
```

Of course you can `$watch` the object to sync it to an array, or you can do it only on submit click for example.

This will allow you to set `ng-model="userAnswers[question.questionId]"`, like:

```
<input type="radio"     
    ng-model="userAnswers[question.questionId]"
    ng-value="answerChoice.answerChoiceId"
    name="elmnt{{question.questionId}}" />
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/6kxx2vLu/8/

See the shape of `userAnswers` just after the save button.

Also click on the save button and scroll to the end to see an example of converting it to an array.

**Update:**

You don't even need the `name` when you use `ng-model`. Angular will handle grouping the `input`s for you based on similar `ng-model`. It wasn't working with the `label` anyway because Angular doesn't support interpolation (expressions) in the `name` of form controls.

The easiest way to get the `label` to work is to make it wrap the `input` as well, like:

```
<label>
    {{answerChoice.answerChoiceAr}}
    <input type="radio"                             
           ng-model="userAnswers[question.questionId]"
           ng-value="answerChoice.answerChoiceId" />
</label>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xqc284xt/

---

Another approach is to use `ng-change`. However in this case you'll need to check the array if it has an object with given question ID or not, to add or update based on that. I wouldn't bother, but comment if you want a code sample showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You an use form input arrays `<input name="foo[]" ... >`

so in your case it will be something like this:

`<input type="radio" name="answers[{{question.questionId}}]" value="{{answerChoice.answerChoiceId}}" />`

Comment: Could you Please try to show me by editing my code online https://jsfiddle.net/6kxx2vLu/

Answer (score 0):

I think, you wanna to handle the onclick event in the radio buttons to collect all selected answers for related questions,

```
<input type="radio" name="elmnt{{question.questionId}}" value="{{answerChoice.answerChoiceId}}" onclick="setValue(event)" />
```

and in js your code :

```
var answer= function(name,value){
    this.name=name;
    this.value=value;
    };

    var questionsAnswers=[];

    function setValue(event){
        var evSrc = event.target;
        var arrLength = questionsAnswers.length;
        questionsAnswers[arrLength]=new answer(evSrc.name,evSrc.value);
    }
```

By trying this you get the selected answers and questions in this array questionsAnswers

So you can handle it in saveAnswers function , like that:

```
 $scope.saveAnswers = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < questionsAnswers.length; i++) {
        alert(questionsAnswers[i].name +' = ' +questionsAnswers[i].value);
    }

   }
```

wish this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

I changed data format which seems to be more logical.

you need to handle `ng-click` for radio input and set the appropriate option as I have set it in each question.

In save function I collected all questionIds and their respective selected answer in an array.

please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiranbobade/aq0dt018/9/), I created for you.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

simply you need a little changes in your code :

To use Radio button you need a model property of field to hold your choice value and to do that use the **ng-model** directive at the radio button which will be the same value in each group of radio buttons

The steps:

1- add new property to your array named **AnswerNumber** at the first level of your array out side the nested array answerChoices

```
 var moCdataForTest = [{
        "questionId": 20,
        "questionAR": "How you Know Our Services?",
        "surveyId": 12,
        "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
        "AnswerNumber" :"",
        "answerChoices": [
         {                  
             "answerChoiceId": 1,
             "questionId": 20,
             "answerChoiceAr": "From web or Google Serach",
             "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
         },
         {
             "answerChoiceId": 2,
             "questionId": 20,
             "answerChoiceAr": "From Frind",
             "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
         },
         {
             "answerChoiceId": 3,
             "questionId": 20,
             "answerChoiceAr": "Newspaper ads",
             "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
         }
        ]
    },
   {
       "questionId": 21,
       "questionAR": "What is your satisfaction level?",
       "surveyId": 12,
       "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
       "AnswerNumber" :"",
       "answerChoices": [
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 4,
            "questionId": 21,
            "answerChoiceAr": "Good",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        },
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 5,
            "questionId": 21,
            "answerChoiceAr": "Very Good",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        },
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 6,
            "questionId": 21,
            "answerChoiceAr": "Excellent",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        }
       ]
   },
   {
       "questionId": 23,
       "questionAR": "What is Visit Rate?",
       "surveyId": 12,
       "qyestionAnswersTypeId": 1,
       "AnswerNumber" :"",
       "answerChoices": [
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 4,
            "questionId": 23,
            "answerChoiceAr": "1Star",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        },
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 5,
            "questionId": 23,
            "answerChoiceAr": "2Star",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        },
        {
            "answerChoiceId": 6,
            "questionId": 23,
            "answerChoiceAr": "3Star",
            "answerChoiceTypeId": 1,
        }
       ]
   }]
```

2- add the ng-model directive to the radio button and set it's value with the name of the new property **AnswerNumber**

```
<input type="radio"  ng-value="answerChoice.answerChoiceId" name="elmnt{{question.questionId}}" 
ng-model="question.AnswerNumber" />
```

3- finally at your scope function **saveAnswers** iterate over the the scope array variable **Questions** to display or add the answers to **$scope.userAnswers** variable

```
            $scope.saveAnswers = function () {
            var values = "";
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.Questions.length; i++) {
                values += $scope.Questions[i].AnswerNumber + "\n";
                $scope.userAnswers[i] = $scope.Questions[i].AnswerNumber;
            }     
            alert($scope.userAnswers);
            //alert(values);
            alert('Data Saved');                
        };
```

I already updated you online code with the answer

Comment: Thanks Yabo Hmeed It Work nice Solution

Answer (score 0):

I've update your jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/6kxx2vLu/7/

I've added ng-model to the input[radio] and bound it to the **question.answer**

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="answerChoice.answerChoiceId" 
             name="elmnt{{question.questionId}}" ng-model="question.answer" />
```

and on save I **map** the questions array like this

```
$scope.answers = $scope.Questions.map(function(q){return q.answer;});
```